# Problem with Forward elimination implementation

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, linear-equation

Let be the following Forward Elimination Implementation in terms of `C#`

```
public static void ForwardElimination(double[,] AugmentedMatrix)
        {
            int N = AugmentedMatrix.GetLength(0);

            for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
            {
                for (int i = k + 1; i < N; i++)
                {
                    double factor = AugmentedMatrix[i, k] / AugmentedMatrix[k, k];

                    for (int j = k; j < N; j++)
                    {
                        AugmentedMatrix[i, j] -= factor * AugmentedMatrix[k, j];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The pseudocode implemented above is:

[image]

Using the `NUnit` test

```
public void TestOfForwardElimination()
        {
            double[,] array = new double[,] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };
            NumericalMethods.ForwardElimination(array);
            Assert.That(array, Is.EqualTo(new double[,] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 0, -3, -6 } }));
        }
```

there is a wrong value as follows

```
Message: 
      Expected and actual are both <System.Double[2,3]>
      Values differ at index [1,2]
      Expected: -6.0d
      But was:  6.0d
```

Where is an error in code and how to fix it ?

Comment: As you can see in the answer of @PraveenB your augmented matrix for a linear equation system of size N is not N x N, but N x N+1. In the image of the pseudo code, there's a big N and a small n which are not the same values. Apart from this problem you should think about A[k, k] == 0 causing a DivideByZeroException. Have a look at pivoting.

Comment: @Petro - updated the answer. Put debug statements so that you can follow the logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your solution is this line. Here you have to go through all the columns so it should be j <= N and not j < N. N is 2, the number of rows so you are missing one iteration in your solution.

```
for (int j = k; j <= N; j++)
```

The algo that you have pasted is for square matrix N x N and not N x M i.e. your case ( 2 x 3 ). If it was a square matrix, the solution would be good.

Here is another take at it @Petro - What you can do is create 2 variables one for rows and one for cols.

```
int m = AugmentedMatrix.GetLength(0);
int n =  AugmentedMatrix.GetLength(1);
```

For the first 2 loops it will be m and for the last loop use n i.e.

```
for (int k = 0; k < m; k++)
for (int i = k + 1; i < m; i++)
```

And for the last one

```
for (int j = k; j < n; j++)
```

Also this will not work if m > n. Also print i,j,k inside every iteration to debug and catch range e.g.

```
Console.WriteLine("i:" + i + ", k:" + k + ", factor: " + factor);
```

Comment: this revision gives an out of range exception, still even for NxN size of array it doesnt work

Comment: You have to modify the solution for NxN as in that case it will exceed the boundary. This  j<=N is for your 2x3 solution. You have to modify based on what dimensions you are passing.  If its NxN and j <= N than it will go up to index N which is wrong.

Comment: Its a simple fix but i would like you to try instead of directly giving you a solution.

Comment: literally have no idea what to change there, any step goes to out of range exception

Comment: Damien you have not read the whole post. Its not a square matrix its NxN+1.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your code with below:

```
        public static void ForwardElimination(double[,] AugmentedMatrix)
        {
            int N0 = AugmentedMatrix.GetLength(0);
            int N1 = AugmentedMatrix.GetLength(1);

            for (int k = 0; k < N0; k++)
            {
                for (int i = k + 1; i < N1-1; i++)
                {
                    double factor = AugmentedMatrix[i, k] / AugmentedMatrix[k, k];

                    for (int j = k; j < N1; j++)
                    {
                        AugmentedMatrix[i, j] -= factor * AugmentedMatrix[k, j];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```